# I want to compare my dictionary key with a value of a 2d list and if the value is right I want to append to a new list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, append, filtering

```
gff_lijst_gefilterd = []
for x in range(1, len(gff_lijst)):
    if filter_genID[x] == x:
        gff_lijst_gefilterd.append(gff_lijst_gefilterd[x])
return gff_lijst_gefilterd
```

So i want this code to loop over gff_lijst which is a 2d list. It checks if the keys of the dictionary are the same of the  8th value of the list and if it does than it appends the value of the list to
the gff_lijst_gefilterd
I hope you can help me!

Comment: So you have a list looking like this `[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 5], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4]]` and you want to see if the `5` and `4` are a key in your dict?

Comment: Yeah I wanne see if those are in my dict and than i want to add those value to a new list. It's more like  [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [4,5,5]] and I want to check on the last value of the 2d list and for example it is 5 I want to have as a new list [[3,4,5], [4,5,5]]. Do you know what I mean now?

Comment: I think so. I'll add an answer and you can correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're much better off just iterating through your 2D list and then checking if the last element is in your dict.

Here is an example:

```
# this is just a test list
gff_lijst = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 5], 
             [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4],
             [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3],
             [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 8],
             [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 9],
             [1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 4],
             [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 6]]

# and a test dict
filter_genID = {3 : 'test', 4 : 'test2'}

gff_lijst_gefilterd = []

# iterate through your 2d list
# in this case i will be each list in your 2d list
for i in gff_lijst:
    # check if the last element of the current list is in your dict keys
    if i[-1] in filter_genID:
        # if it is we add it to our list
        gff_lijst_gefilterd.append(i)

print(gff_lijst_gefilterd)
```